# Count Values comma separated non-numeric (Google Sheets)

Tags: count, google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to get a count of answers inside a cell which are comma-separated in this format: Anna, peter, Hans, Otto (here it should be 4)

Need this for an assignment and nothing seems to work and my programming are very limited so I hope someone might help me out here :/

I have tried it in excel first with this formula:

```
=LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),",",""))+1
```

..which didn't work (the brackets around the first A1 and after substitute turned red - whats that telling us anyway? My search only show me entries about negative values..)

Then I tried this formula here in google spreadsheet:

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(A1; ","))
```

..which also didn't work (here I simply get an error).

I guess it's about the values being non numeric? Any ideas?

Comment: You are using two different local formats.  Depending on your local settings you would either use `;` or `,` as the deliminator between the criteria.

Comment: Thanks Scott - Sadly I have no clue what you just said (: It might be an explanation - what do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you need:

```
=LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1);",";""))+1
```

If your Regional Settings require it. *(see Scott's comment)*

Comment: This is it :) Thanks a lot (also @scott)! I didn't know about those regional settings..

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1
```

It just counts the commas and adds `1`

**Update**
I just realized that's pretty much the same as what you had - just without using `TRIM` which isn't necessary. Your formula should work too.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, use:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")) + 1
```

Unless there is a chance for A having no value, then you need to expand it farther:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>0,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")) + 1,0)
```

Since you also tagged Google Spreadsheets, there use:

```
=COUNTA( SPLIT(A1, ",", TRUE))
```

Same applies for the possiblity of an empty field in Google Sheets.

Comment: Hi Karl! Thanks but both sadly don't work. Google just gives me an error and in excel I get the red brackets

Comment: Interesting.  I tested both by copying in your sample cell data and they worked.  What is the Error shown in Google when you hover your cursor over the cell?

Comment: Also, @pRod,  regarding the comments about using a semi-colon or a comma to separate items: In some regions you must use a semicolon (;) instead of a comma.  Might try changing the commas to semicolons.

Comment: Thanks so much karl! It all make sense now why it seems to work for everybody so easily but not for me :) I sure can use the expansion.part - thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome, @pRod .  If you use Google Sheets, I used this to test for a blank cell first: `=IF(ISBLANK(G1:G),0,COUNTA(SPLIT(G1:G, ",")))`